# Como eu faço para configurar o timeout da chamada de uma função de um EJB?

Tags: java, spring, ejb, timeout, settimeout

No final de um serviço do meu projeto tem uma função que pega um EJB de outro projeto que está instalado no mesmo servidor, e acessa uma de suas funções.

Minha função que pega o EJB e acessa a função:

```
[...]

ServiceImplRemote serviceImplRemote = 
beanFactory.getBean("ServiceImplEJB",ServiceImplRemote.class);
Collection<UserDTO> result = 
serviceImplRemote.userRequired(**parametro da função**, **parametro da função**);
return result;

[...]
```

O que eu quero fazer é configurar o timeout da chamada `serviceImplRemote.userRequired()` pois o timeout default é muito pequeno e o processamento dessa função demora muito. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar a [seguinte anotação](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/AccessTimeout.html) no método que está demorando:

```
    @AccessTimeout(value = 15, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    @Override
    public void metodoDemorado() {
        //implementação
    }
```